# C++ Operator+ string long produces Segmentation Fault

Tags: c++

The following code produces a segmentation fault with only the xxx line printed (ie before the "pre concat").

```
cerr << "xxx + " << ((long long) timev);
string cname = "MyKey" + ((long long) timev);

string operator+(const string& str, long long nr) {
  cerr << "Pre concat "; // << str << "$" << nr;
  stringstream ss;
  ss << str << nr;
  cerr << "Post concat";
  return ss.str();
}
```

Any idea why?

(I will just use a method, overloading operators on standard types is probably a bad idea as it is likely to conflict with other modules.  But damned if I can see what is wrong with this.)

Comment: What is the declaration of `timev`?

Comment: Look at the output of `std::cout << "MyKey" + 2;`. You would have spotted a problem if you'd used `+` in the preceding line instead of `<<`.

Comment: Learn to use a debugger.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`"MyKey"` is not `std::string`. It's `const char[6]`. And for `"MyKey" + ((long long) timev)`, your overloading operator won't be called. Instead, `"MyKey"` will decay to `const char*`, then `"MyKey" + ((long long) timev)` might get out of the bound of the array, which is  [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

The code is equivalent as:

```
const char* key = "MyKey";
string cname = key + ((long long) timev); // or key[((long long) timev)]
```

You could

```
string cname = string("MyKey") + ((long long) timev);
```

Comment: @juanchopanza OP defined one. Is it not acceptable?

Comment: Oh, I see. No, I don't think that is allowed.

Comment: @juanchopanza So back to my first quesiont. Does the overloading for standard lib types not allowed? (I know some issues about this, such as stl template specification only allowed for user type, is it this issue here?)

Comment: @juanchopanza It *is* allowed and well-defined.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Do you have a reference?

Comment: @songyuanyao I don't think it is. I will look it up. Maybe the restriction only applies to overloading inside the `std` namespace.

Comment: @juanchopanza Thanks. I'll look up too.

Comment: @juanchopanza I've checked the standard and I found no restrictions on types for which you overload operators. The only restriction is that *at least one* of operator's arguments must be a class. Maybe it's UB to put the operator's definition into `std::`, but there is no reason to do so anyway if you can put it into global namespace.

Comment: I think you mean std::string("MyKey") + std::to_string((long long) timev);

Comment: @Loreto Nah, OP has defined `std::string + long long` operator in his code.

Comment: Yes, I love it.  The glory of C++.  It did not occur to me that + would add pointers.  I wounder if there is a way to totally deactivate that type of pointer arithmetic?  Use [] where needed instead.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat It may be allowed, but I think it is a bad idea.  Modern software combines different modules.  This is asking for a clash between independently declared operators.